# I did more than 500 edits and received a copy editor

Tags: bug

I did more than 500 edits and received a copy editor badge but on my profile page It is mentioned that I did only 455+ edits and sometimes my profile page says 36k people have reached and then 56k.A bug may be?

Comment: Seems likely some posts you edited got removed since you earned that badge last year, dupes, off topics etc... As for the people reached, it says 56k if I look at your profile.